# Error 429 when trying to create a ADODB.Connection Object

Tags: excel, adodb, vba

I've created an Excel Userform that connects with an Access DB to retrive the User pending tasks and list it with the status. This excel file is run by 6 analists without issues but one has recieved the Runtime Error 429: The activeX component cannot create Object.

The user who got the error is the only using a x86 windows.

I've tried all versions of the MS ActiveX Data Objects x.x Library in the XL references unsuccessfull

I also tried to install the Access Database Engine and the error still coming

Following the code:

```
Public Const conStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data   Source=\\SAO229DT91264\Planej_dev\Planilhao.accdb;Persist Security   Info=False;"
Public CN As ADODB.Connection
Public RS As ADODB.Recordset
_______________________________________________________________
Function importDB(ByVal filter As String)
    Dim line As Long
    Dim col As Long
    Dim tim  As Date
    Dim user As String
    Dim query As String

    query = "Select Code, indice, flNO, dtStart, dtEnd, Pattern, orig, std, sta, dest, mkt, resp, order, motiv, status, action, obs, dtMsg, numMsg, dtVigencia, daysOps, dtAdd, dtChg from Alterations"

    tim = Now()
    user = CStr(Application.UserName)

    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection 'The code stops here With the runtime error
    Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

    WS.Unprotect

    line = WS.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If linha > 2 Then WS.Range(WS.Cells(3, 1), WS.Cells(linha, 23)).ClearContents

    CN.Open conStr
    RS.Open query & " " & filter & " order by code asc;", CN

    line = 2

    Do While Not RS.EOF
        line = line + 1
        For col = 1 To RS.Fields.Count
            If col = 4 Or col = 5 Then
                WS.Cells(line, col).NumberFormat = "@"
                WS.Cells(line, col) = CStr(Format(RS.Fields(col - 1).Value, "dd/MMM/YYYY"))
            Else
                WS.Cells(line, col) = RS.Fields(col - 1).Value
            End If
        Next col
        RS.MoveNext
    Loop

    CN.Close
    WS.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
    , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
    End Function
```

Comment: What do you mean by
"The user who got the error is the only using a x86 windows"
Do you mean 32bit, or the others are using Wine or a MAC?

Comment: All other users are using 64bit windows

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by removing the reference to adodb in Tools,references on the failing machine, save and close. Reopen and reset the reference, then recompile.